# JavaFX - MVC app doesn't work when all classes are seperated (in other packages)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

my app works only when all classes are in application package, when I want to seperate them for particular packages (model, controller, view) it doesn't work, when I change path in Main class to "/src/view/Login.fxml" then error appears: "location is required".. what I did wrong?

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/src/view/Login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,280,280);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

[here is a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvtdg.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code, instead of posting links to images (which can't be copied and pasted, among other issues). Read the [help pages on formatting code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) if you need to. You might also want to read on how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: From your screen shot, though, it looks like the `view` folder is not being deployed along with the class files. What is in the build folder (probably called "bin")?

Comment: bin folder looks same like src folder - application, model, view, controller (but in bin folder all classes can be launch by InteliJ, here are icons InteliJ on these files.. but Im using Eclipse) and in src folder these icons are blank, like they haven't assigned default IDE.. im not sure if it matters?

Comment: Well, hold on. The screen shot shows `"/view/Login.fxml"`, which is correct, and also shows a different error (something is wrong on line 10 of `Login.fxml`.). Your posted code shows `"/src/view/Login.fxml"`, which is not available at runtime (it's in the src folder, not the compiled bin folder), hence the location error.

Comment: Yes, because I tried with these two options, with /view/Login.fxml and /src/view/Login.fxml and none of them works..so first option is correct? but it doesn't work as well :(

Comment: Yes, the first option is correct. It is a different error. Since it gives you the line number in the FXML file where the error occurs, I think it's pretty safe to assume it managed to find the FXML file, no?

Comment: Problem solved! It was all about to change in FXML file that line: "fx:controller="application.LoginController" I change 'application' to 'controller' and now is fine, thank you